# Volume quotient in Carnot-cycle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, entropy, ideal-gas, carnot-cycle

Problem:

> One kilomole of an ideal, monatomic gas undergoes a reversible Carnot-processes between temperatures 300 °C and 20 °C. The work done during one cycle is 1500 kJ.
>
> a) Find the entropy-change in every process and show that total sum of entropy-changes is zero
>
> b) What is the ratio between the largest and smallest volume that the gas takes on during the whole process?

I have already done a), it is b) I am struggling with. I realized that the greatest and smallest volume is assumed in the adiabatic processes of the Carnot-cycle, so I applied $T_1V_1^{\gamma -1} = T_1V_1^{\gamma -1}$ but to no avail. How can one do it?

Comment: Did you convert temperature to degrees Kelvin?

Comment: Sure. But the maximum and smallest volume lies on different adiabatic curves, so that's an issue I am not sure how to bypass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The total work done by the system in one cycle is the sum of the works done in the isothermal processes:
[image]
$$W_{total}=nR\left ( T_h\ln \frac{V_2}{V_1}-T_c\ln\frac{V_3}{V_4} \right )$$
Also for adiabatic processes we have :
$$T_h V_2^{\gamma-1 }=T_c V_3^{\gamma-1}\tag{2}$$
$$T_hV_1^{\gamma-1}=T_cV_4^{\gamma-1}\tag{3}$$
Substituting for $V_2$ and $V_4$ from $(2)$ and $(3)$ in the first equation, we can find the ratio $V_3\over V_1$. (Find the final result yourself!)

Comment: What about work done in the adiabatic processes? Don't they contribute to the total work?

Comment: In the adiabatic processes $\Delta U=\Delta W$. Also, $\Delta U$ only depends on the temperature difference, so the total work in these two processes is zero.

Comment: Yes but the temperature is changing (decreasing in fact) and thus $\Delta U \neq 0$, right? Or wait do you mean that work done from 2 to 3 cancels out with the work done from 4 to 1?

Comment: Yeah, exactly .

Comment: All right thanks. By the way: The work done in the adiabatic process (from 2 to 3), is it $\frac {nRT_2 - nrT_1}{\gamma -1}$ where $T_2$ is the temperature for the isotherm from 3 to 4 and $T_1$ is the temperature for the isotherm from 1 to 2.

Comment: Yes. Because in adiabatic processes $\Delta W=\Delta U=\alpha nR\Delta T$ where $\alpha=\frac{1}{\gamma-1}$.